# Frontend Editing in Joomla 3.4 is not working

Tags: joomla, frontend, k2

I have enabled:

```
Global Configuration –> Mouse-over Edit Icons for: -> Module&Menus
```

`Global Configuration –> Articles -> Editing Layout -> Show Publishing Options -> Yes` ----- and also `Show Article Options`, `Enable Versions` is set to yes.

I'm logged in in front-end and back-end as Super User.

In every ACL Super User Frontend Editing is set to Allowed.

Joomla 3.4

K2 v2.6.9

Purity_III 1.1.2

...........

I still can’t edit in frontend.

How to enable Frontend Editing? For articles, K2 Items, menus, modules.

What am I missing?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is depending on the template. You have to ask to JoomlArt if they manage this function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in to the front end - this can be done using the Login Module or a menu link to the Login Component.

The front-end editing is 'automatic' when you put the site offline and and log in to view it, because of course we are logged in to the front-end!

But when the site is put online, we forget this bit!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your template has css declarations for the edit button. i.e.-

```
.btn.jmodedit {
    background:#000 !important;
}
.icon-edit:before {
    content: 'edit';
    color:#fff;
}
```